# WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker + dropdown-toggle-split

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
                    wp_nav_menu( [
                        'menu' => 'Menu 1',
                    'depth'           => 2,
                    'container'       => false,
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                    'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
                ] );
```

Использую класс WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker для Wordpress. На мобильной версии нужно добавить в выпадающие меню отдельно кнопку для открытия 2 уровня. 
Пример 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#split-button

Answer (score 0):

Временное решение с помощью js

```
 $('.nav-item.dropdown').append('<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>');
```

Answer (score 0):

В методе display_element класса WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker в нужном месте добавьте:

```
if ( $depth > 1 ) {
    // кнопка
}
```

и скройте кнопку с помощью css на десктопе.